# Debugging on actual device, need file access - how?

Tags: android, debugging

My app reads and processes data stored in .xml format on the device.  Works fine when installed.

However, I prefer to debug using Eclipse on the phone itself instead of using an emulator.  But, this precludes file system access.

Is there a way around this?  Debugging on the device is so much nicer in my opinion.

Comment: For what files/directories you need access?

Comment: as you are new here, please become familiar with concept of answer accepting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way around this?

Root your device.

Answer (score 0):

you may save your files to SD card and access them as `/sdcard` from `adb shell` or from Eclipse debug.

besides that, you may root your device and get unlimited access to any files, very useful for debugging purposes, just don't forget to unroot back when done debugging.